# "Migrations" ran out of gas

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I am trying to deploy 3 contracts to Avalanche. I have already deployed these same contracts to Ropsten, Rinkeby, and Ethereum mainnet.

When I try to deploy to Avalanche, I get this error message:

> Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

> "Migrations" ran out of gas (using Truffle's estimate.)
>
> - Block limit:  8000000 (0x7a1200)
> - Gas sent:     NaN (0xNaN)
> - Try:
>   Setting a higher gas estimate multiplier for this contract
>   Making your contract smaller
>   Making your contract constructor more efficient
>   Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a
>   private network or test client (like ganache).

If I set gas in truffle.config, it still fails no matter what I set. Even if I set the gas limit all the way up to the maximum for the block, it still fails.

For example, if I set it to `3000000`, I get this:

> Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

> "Migrations" ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment parameters.)
>
> - Block limit:  8000000 (0x7a1200)
> - Gas sent:     3000000 (0x2dc6c0)

Or if I set to `8000000`, I get a similar message.

When I deployed to Rinkeby, it cost 2,460,214 units of gas. When I deployed to Ethereum mainnet, it cost 1,118,450 for the first two contracts.

Is there any way to fix this or should I just abandon Avalanche and deploy to some other network?

Here is my truffle.config file:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
 const { projectUrl, mnemonicPhrase } = require('./secrets.json');
 const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
       const fs = require('fs');
 

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Networks define how you connect to your ethereum client and let you set the
   * defaults web3 uses to send transactions. If you don't specify one truffle
   * will spin up a development blockchain for you on port 9545 when you
   * run `develop` or `test`. You can ask a truffle command to use a specific
   * network from the command line, e.g
   *
   * $ truffle test --network <network-name>
   */

   
   contracts_build_directory: './admin-page/src/artifacts/',

  networks: {
    development: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
    port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
    network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },

    rinkeby: {
      provider: function() { 
       return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonicPhrase, projectUrl);
      },
      network_id: 43114,
      gasPrice: 10000000000,
  },

  avalanche: {
    provider: function() { 
     return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonicPhrase, projectUrl);
    },
    network_id: 1,
    gas: 3000000,
    gasPrice: 50,
},


  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
    version: "0.8.0",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      optimizer: {
      enabled: false,   
      runs: 200
      },
      evmVersion: "byzantium"
      }
    }
  },



  db: {
    enabled: false
  },

};
```

Comment: try running it with optimizer enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried with optimizer and got the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: that was my solution that worked for me last time, unfortunately i have no other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Truffle v5.4.16 (except in my case it worked everywhere except on Mainnet) but **after upgrading to Truffle v5.4.33 the issue seem to disappear**.